# Can't see ICustomTypeProvider in .Net Portable Subset

Tags: silverlight-5.0, system.reflection, portable-class-library

I created a portable class library in a project to hold some common code inside a Silverlight 5 solution. I would like to implement the ICustomTypeProvider to create some flexible objects, but I can't see the interface in the PCL, even if I only choose the .Net Framework and SL5 to be the targets for the library.

System.Reflection appears in both the 4.5 framework and SL5, so why can't I see the interface?

Comment: After more digging around, the pure reason is that the interface is declared in System.Windows.dll not in the core System.Reflection.dll.  Not sure why it's there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question in the [Visual Studio Gallery Portable Library Tools Discussion](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/view/Discussions/) (search for question titled **ICustomTypeProvider** currently on page 2, I can't link it directly, what are MS thinking).

Reply by David M. Kean:

> Currently the missing types issue is a point-in-time issue (ie it will
>   get better in the future), and comes down due to our lack of thinking
>   about "portability" when we were working on down-level platforms and
>   APIs. On newer platforms (Windows Store apps, .NET 4.5), we expose the
>   true subset, ie everything that is common between Windows Store apps
>   and .NET 4.5 is consumable from portable. The same will be true for
>   newer versions of unannounced platforms.